# Export csv from SQLite using appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, export-to-csv, titanium-mobile

I beginner in using appcelerator to develop android apps. I tried to export all data that store in db(sqlite) my apps to csv file but the output not display all the data. I using while and array in my code.

```
btn_search.addEventListener('click',function(e) { 

var db = Ti.Database.install('../products.sqlite','products');
var dbName = db.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE doc_num ="'+doc_num.value+'"');

// option 2
while (dbName.isValidRow()) {
var Barcode1 = dbName.fieldByName('doc_num');
var ItemName1 = dbName.fieldByName('barcode');
var UOM1 = dbName.fieldByName('product_name');
var TOUM1 = dbName.fieldByName('rack_loc');
var TQTY1 = dbName.fieldByName('oum');
var TRACK1 = dbName.fieldByName('qty');
dbName.next();

// create csv
var dbName1 = dbName;

dbName1 = [ dbName.fieldByName('doc_num') , dbName.fieldByName('barcode') , dbName.fieldByName('product_name') , dbName.fieldByName('rack_loc') , dbName.fieldByName('oum') , dbName.fieldByName('qty')];

for(var i=0; i<dbName1.length !==0; i++)
{
    Ti.API.info(dbName1[i]);
    alert('you have "'+dbName1[i]+'" in your side');

}

 var outputFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'File_Product.csv');
    outputFile.write(dbName1); 

//alert("Output file = "+ op);

}
```

});

The output only show the one data that the latest data in the db. It should have 3 data. But only show 1 data : DISK1 | 9789678606387| Book1 | A100 | PCS | 12

Can help/advise me to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that in the csv file there is only the latest row?

Comment: `alert("Output file = "+ op);`. What is `op`?

Comment: If there are three rows then `Titanium.Filesystem.getFile()` will be called three times. And every time a new file will be created which is empty. So only the last one will survive. You should open the file in `append` mode instead.

Comment: Yes csv file only display the latest row. Sorry "op" line is comment line in my coding I forgot to comment here. How to Open the file in append mode instead? @greensapps

Comment: Dont know. Dont know titanium.

Comment: You just can open the file before the while loop of course.

Comment: Yes I will try. tq

Answer (score 0):

Update your while loop with below code

```
var main_array = [];    
while (dbName.isValidRow()) {    
    var Barcode1 = dbName.fieldByName('doc_num');
    var ItemName1 = dbName.fieldByName('barcode');
    var UOM1 = dbName.fieldByName('product_name');
    var TOUM1 = dbName.fieldByName('rack_loc');
    var TQTY1 = dbName.fieldByName('oum');
    var TRACK1 = dbName.fieldByName('qty');

    var single_item_array = [dbName.fieldByName('doc_num'),dbName.fieldByName('barcode'), dbName.fieldByName('product_name'), dbName.fieldByName('rack_loc'), dbName.fieldByName('oum'), dbName.fieldByName('qty')];

    for (var i = 0; i < single_item_array.length !== 0; i++) {
        Ti.API.info(single_item_array[i]);
        Ti.API.info("you have > " + single_item_array[i] + " in your side");

    }

    main_array.push(single_item_array);
    dbName.next();
}

if (main_array.length > 0) {
    var outputFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, 'File_Product.csv');
    outputFile.write(main_array);
}
```

Above code resolve your issues.

Comment: Tq for your response and I really appreciate it . But still not resolve the problem.

Comment: there are the complete code for export csv in my program.